# AppArmor unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE

Tags: 16.04, apparmor

On a freshly installed Ubuntu, with only a few packages added, after trying to restart apparmor, it does not start anymore, giving the same error for all profiles

```
-- Unit apparmor.service has begun starting up.
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/lxc-containers in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.lxc-start in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.lxd.lxd-bridge-proxy in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/lxc-containers in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.lxc-start in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.lxd.lxd-bridge-proxy in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/kernelvars at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_SET_VAR, expecting TOK_END_OF_RULE
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel apparmor[1922]:    ...fail!
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=123
Jan 14 17:36:24 panel systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
```

If I comment out a line in kernelvars, it gives an error on the next line for @{tid}. Commenting out all lines, gives an error on another file that's setting a var. How can I fix it?

Comment: You will probably need to file a bug report. What version of Ubuntu ? Is your system all up to date ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, freshly installed and updated. After installing php, nginx and mysql, when I tried to restart apparmor I got this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `apparmor_parser -qp /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient` I saw that the error was from the previous loaded profile `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias` which did not have a comma at the end (did not pay attention after adding the mysql lib alias).